# Merge Sort Variations

Tags: algorithm, sorting

It is required to merge 4 sorted arrays A, B, C and D. Any one of these techniques are allowed :

1. Apply 4-way merge.
2. Merge A and B. Merge C with the output of previous merge. Finally merge D with the last output.
3. Merge A with B and C with D. Now merge the two outputs.

What are the merits and demerits of each of these techniques, in regard to comparisons and transfers?

Comment: The third has the advantage of parallelism, if done right.

Answer (score 2):

There are two measures of efficiency to consider here:

a. memory usage.

b. performance.

The first technique has low memory usage, because it doesn't produce intermediate arrays.

The third technique has high performance, because A/B and C/D can be merged in parallel after which the intermediate arrays are merged.

Lastly, the second technique has neither of the above traits.

Comment: This is not really with "regard to comparisons and transfers".

Comment: @Dukeling Feel free to change it, it's CW after all ;-)

Comment: Well, it seems to be distinct from the answer, so it would be a rather significant edit, in which case I'd rather post my own answer. But I haven't quite thought it through yet (nor will I try to).